# CircleCI test passing but not publishing to NPM

Tags: npm, circleci

My CI tests pass but I'm not sure why my packages aren't being published to npm.

The snippet below shows the areas I think I may have the problem with

```
  deploy:
    <<: *defaults
    steps:
      - attach_workspace:
          at: ~/emotion-emoji
      - run:
          name: Authenticate with registry
          command: echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=$npm_TOKEN" > ~/.npmrc
      - run:
          name: Publish package
          command: npm publish
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the console output in CircleCI?

Comment: I resolved the issue. I needed to push a tag with the format v1.x.x

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. I needed to push a tag with the format v1.x.x